# Names of grammatical constructions that coordinate partial clauses

Tags: grammaire, subordonnées, coordination

I have the following three sentences and would like to know how the corresponding grammatical constructions are called:

- *Gérard connaît et aime Alice* : is it a coordination of verbs??
- *Gérard connaît, et pourrait épouser, Alice* : subordonnée? and if yes, of which kind?
- *Gérard aime, et Philippe déteste, Alice* : ??? (same question)

I have looked in the Bescherelle but couldn't find any examples coming near to these ones. These are constructions targeted by Steedman's CCG approaches, what I need is their names, in French terminology.

Comment: I guess they are a specific kind of “interpolated clauses” (“propositions incises” in French). You could maybe find something starting from there.

Comment: I the examples I have seen, the proposition incise seems quite independent from the rest of the sentence (as in «Mais, madame, *demanda Charlotte*, de quelle façon une Italienne est-elle jalouse ?» found in Wikipedia), here in the first two cases it shares both subject and COD, in the third it has a different subject but the same COD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Case 2 and three are different only in that you can emphasize them with commas, but syntactically they all are the same thing: coordinated sentences with ellipsis. It seems that *conjunction reduction* and *right node raising* are terms in syntactical theory for at least some presentations of the phenomenon (I do not know their exact equivalent, if any, in French).

Grevisse (*Bon Usage*, 14th ed.) discuss these in §269. But there's really not much to say as that particular feature of syntax is pretty much universal amongst languages:

> Quand, dans des termes coordonnés, il y a des éléments identiques, la tendance naturelle est de ne pas répéter ces éléments communs.